# react-dom.production.min.js:216 "TypeError: s.map is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, express, mern

I have the following error `react-dom.production.min.js:216 "TypeError: s.map is not a function` due to this code :

`sidebar.jsx`

```
const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCats = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/categories");
      setCats(res.data);
    };
    getCats();
  }, []);

...

<span className="sidebarTitle">CATEGORIES</span>
        <ul className="sidebarList">
          {cats.map((c) => (
            <Link to={`/?cat=${c.name}`} className="link">
              <li className="sidebarListItem">{c.name}</li>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

I want to display these categories in a sidebar in a Website made with MERN.

[image: Database]

**The code to reproduce it :**

**index.js** (in the server part)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: true
  })
  .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  

app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

app.listen("3000", () => {
  console.log("Backend is running.");
});
```

**routes/categories.js**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Category = require("../models/Category");

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const newCat = new Category(req.body);
  try {
    const savedCat = await newCat.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedCat);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const cats = await Category.find();
      res.status(200).json(cats);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

**models/Category.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);
```

I now want to pass everything to the front-end (REACT) to display it on the screen. The code corresponding to the front-end is named **sidebar.jsx** (I put the code a bit above).

Do you have any idea to make it right?

Comment: I'd guess that `res.data` isn't an array, but without a [mre] it's hard to say.

Comment: Where is `s.map` in the code?

Comment: I don't have ```s.map``` only ```cats.map```. The error correspond to my ```cats.map``` line

Comment: You should try running your code in debug mode so you can see the actual variable names. Even before, that, add some `console.log` so you can know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the api you are not getting data in array format. Please check if your api is returning array.

Comment: Yes, with a console.log I saw yesterday that the array was empty which explains the error. Unfortunately, i wasn't able to understand why the API is not returning the right values. Do you have any idea to connect to the database with mongoose ?